# Pivoting MultiIndex Data

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a MultiIndex pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Input]

I want the different quarters as rows instead of hierarchial columns i.e. a long format instead of this wide one. Something like this (output need not be a multindex):

[image: output]

How can I do this in Pandas?

Edit:

Sample input file as requested:

[rbi_credits_data.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unIsKfplAy9I46Heyu5jJ6oK3DJm0hQV/view?usp=sharing)

Sample Data(Pandas):

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Center_Details', '2017-18:Q2', '2017-18:Q1'],
                       ['State', 'District', 'Center', 'Offices', 'Deposit', 'Credit']],
               labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]])
data = [['JAMMU & KASHMIR', 'KUPWARA', 'Drug Mulla (CT)', '3', '500', '600', '4', '500', '600'], 
    ['JAMMU & KASHMIR', 'LEH LADAKH', 'Chuglamsar (CT)', '3', '500', '600', '4', '500', '600'], 
    ['PUNJAB', 'PATHANKOT', 'Mamun (CT)', '3', '500', '600', '4', '500', '600'], 
    ['PUNJAB', 'GURDASPUR', 'TIBRI', '3', '500', '600', '4', '500', '600']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
```

Comment: @mudassirkhan19 please take the time to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5241032). It's also generally a bad practice to provide links to files in questions, especially when asking questions about pandas dataframes.

Comment: In R, you would probably just use `melt` from the "data.table" package. R does not support hierarchical column names though.

Comment: @cmaher Thanks for the link to the guidelines, I have given the link to the file in this case because I don't know how to generate sample multiindex data in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to just flatten the `MultiIndex` and use `melt` and `pivot_table`, something like this:

```
# Flatten the MultiIndex columns
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]

# Save some typing
idx = ['Center_Details State', 'Center_Details District', 'Center_Details Center']

# Create a long dataframe
long = pd.melt(df, id_vars = idx)

# Split the "variable" column at the space created when flattening the MultiIndex
long['QTR'], long['item'] = zip(*long['variable'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')))

# Reshape to wide format, keeping "QTR" as a column
out = pd.pivot_table(long, index = idx + ["QTR"], columns = 'item', 
                     values = 'value', aggfunc = 'first').reset_index()
print(out)
item Center_Details State Center_Details District Center_Details Center  \
0         JAMMU & KASHMIR                 KUPWARA       Drug Mulla (CT)   
1         JAMMU & KASHMIR                 KUPWARA       Drug Mulla (CT)   
2         JAMMU & KASHMIR              LEH LADAKH       Chuglamsar (CT)   
3         JAMMU & KASHMIR              LEH LADAKH       Chuglamsar (CT)   
4                  PUNJAB               GURDASPUR                 TIBRI   
5                  PUNJAB               GURDASPUR                 TIBRI   
6                  PUNJAB               PATHANKOT            Mamun (CT)   
7                  PUNJAB               PATHANKOT            Mamun (CT)   

item         QTR Credit Deposit Offices  
0     2017-18:Q1    600     500       4  
1     2017-18:Q2    600     500       3  
2     2017-18:Q1    600     500       4  
3     2017-18:Q2    600     500       3  
4     2017-18:Q1    600     500       4  
5     2017-18:Q2    600     500       3  
6     2017-18:Q1    600     500       4  
7     2017-18:Q2    600     500       3
```

---

Another option might be something like:

```
long = df.set_index(['Center_Details']).stack().T.unstack()
long = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(long.reset_index()['Center_Details'].tolist()), 
                  long.reset_index()], axis=1)
long.columns = ['State', 'District', 'Center', 'Center_Details', 
                'Items', 'QTR', 'Value']
out = pd.pivot_table(long, index=['State', 'District', 'Center', 'QTR'], 
                     columns='Items', values='Value', 
                     aggfunc='first').reset_index()
print(out)
Items            State    District           Center         QTR Credit  \
0      JAMMU & KASHMIR     KUPWARA  Drug Mulla (CT)  2017-18:Q1    600   
1      JAMMU & KASHMIR     KUPWARA  Drug Mulla (CT)  2017-18:Q2    600   
2      JAMMU & KASHMIR  LEH LADAKH  Chuglamsar (CT)  2017-18:Q1    600   
3      JAMMU & KASHMIR  LEH LADAKH  Chuglamsar (CT)  2017-18:Q2    600   
4               PUNJAB   GURDASPUR            TIBRI  2017-18:Q1    600   
5               PUNJAB   GURDASPUR            TIBRI  2017-18:Q2    600   
6               PUNJAB   PATHANKOT       Mamun (CT)  2017-18:Q1    600   
7               PUNJAB   PATHANKOT       Mamun (CT)  2017-18:Q2    600   

Items Deposit Offices  
0         500       4  
1         500       3  
2         500       4  
3         500       3  
4         500       4  
5         500       3  
6         500       4  
7         500       3
```

---

A third option is to use `wide_to_long`, but `wide_to_long` expects that the columns in the wide format have stubs at the start. The approach is similar to the first approach, but involves fewer steps.

It looks something like:

```
# Flatten the column names, but reverse the order of the tuples
#   before flattening, and add a character to split on
df.columns = ['~'.join(col[::-1]).strip() for col in df.columns.values]

# Reshape the data, Stata-style
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Offices', 'Deposit', 'Credit'], 
   i=['State~Center_Details', 'District~Center_Details', 'Center~Center_Details'],
   j='Quarter', sep='~').reset_index()
```

You'll still have to do some cleanup on the "Center_Details" columns.

Comment: Thank you! you taught me a bunch of stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's answer a little bit, I found that I can still keep the multiindex structure:

```
idx = df[['Center_Details']].columns.values.tolist()
long = pd.melt(df, id_vars = idx)

# Renaming variable created by melt to a multiindex friendly name
long.rename(columns={'variable_0': ('Values', 'Qtr')}, inplace=True)

# Reshape to wide format, keeping Values, QTR as a hierarchical column
out = pd.pivot_table(long, index = idx + [('Values', 'Qtr')], columns = 'variable_1', 
                 values = 'value', aggfunc = 'first')

# Creating tuples for new column names
out.columns = [('Values', col) for col in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index()
# Converting columns to multiindex
out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.columns.values)
print(out)

+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
|   | Center_Details  |            |                 | Values     |        |         |         |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
|   | State           | District   | Center          | QTR        | Credit | Deposit | Offices |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 0 | JAMMU & KASHMIR | KUPWARA    | Drug Mulla (CT) | 2017-18:Q1 | 600    | 500     | 4       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 1 | JAMMU & KASHMIR | KUPWARA    | Drug Mulla (CT) | 2017-18:Q2 | 600    | 500     | 3       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2 | JAMMU & KASHMIR | LEH LADAKH | Chuglamsar (CT) | 2017-18:Q1 | 600    | 500     | 4       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 3 | JAMMU & KASHMIR | LEH LADAKH | Chuglamsar (CT) | 2017-18:Q2 | 600    | 500     | 3       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 4 | PUNJAB          | GURDASPUR  | TIBRI           | 2017-18:Q1 | 600    | 500     | 4       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 5 | PUNJAB          | GURDASPUR  | TIBRI           | 2017-18:Q2 | 600    | 500     | 3       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 6 | PUNJAB          | PATHANKOT  | Mamun (CT)      | 2017-18:Q1 | 600    | 500     | 4       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 7 | PUNJAB          | PATHANKOT  | Mamun (CT)      | 2017-18:Q2 | 600    | 500     | 3       |
+---+-----------------+------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

PS: Sorry for the ugly table formatting, I still have no idea how to create tables on SO.